# How to use order by clause on DATENAME() to sort Day name

Tags: sql-server-2008

My query is this

```
SELECT        DATENAME(dw, date) AS DayOnDate
FROM            datetbl
```

And  output is:

```
Saturday
Sunday
Saturday
Sunday
Monday
Tuesday
```

i want to sort this day name like

```
Tuesday 
Monday
Saturday
Saturday
Sunday
Sunday
```

Comment: I don't understand the ordering you're trying to get. They're not in same order as the days are in the week.

Comment: You really want "Sunday" to sort between "Monday" and "Wednesday"?

Answer (score 0):

Your expected ordering is odd, but if your intention is that all the rows with the same day name appear together then all you need to do is add 
ORDER BY DATENAME(dw,date) after FROM datetbl

Answer (score 0):

Your example looks like you want to order by descending Week day, so try using

```
SELECT        DATENAME(dw, date) AS DayOnDate
FROM            datetbl
ORDER BY    WEEKDAY(date) DESC
```

This won't give you the exact ordering you give, so you will have to apply some kind of offset. I can't tell you what that is because you haven't shown all the days of the week.